# AWS Data Pipeline - current filename as variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have `S3DataNode` with specified `Directory Path` instead of one file. This node is populated from external sources with variety of different files. I would like to insert information about the current filename when inserting data row to RDS table. Is there a way to obtain current filename?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no obvious way to do it. One option could be to run additional step that will modify S3 files by appending filename to each row in file.

Comment: Yes this is an option but I suppose I will use other tool for that part. I supposed that there will be no obvious way to do it.. Maybe in next version ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no native support to refer to a file being read in Data Pipeline.